# Double Count Select return wrong result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello I am using the following query to display the count of the rows where id is the same number from first table, I have 2 more tables. If I leave only one count evertything is working fine but with double count select I am getting the same result which is wrong:

```
'SELECT c.*, count(s.userID) as count_consulta, count(a.userID) as count_asesoria
   FROM users as c 
   LEFT JOIN consulta AS s ON s.userID = c.userID 
   LEFT JOIN asesoria AS a ON a.userID = c.userID
   GROUP BY c.userID DESC'
```

with this I am getting:

```
count_consulta = 15
count_asesoria = 15
```

where it should be

```
count_consulta = 3
count_asesoria = 5
```

any help will be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Could you be looking for `count(distinct s.userID)` and `count(distinct a.userID)`? If an `id` appears more than once in a table (maybe you have a composite primary key of multiple fields to break up a many-to-many relationship), it'll be counted every time unless you specifically ask for the values to be distinct.

Comment: this way I am getting result 1 on both

Comment: Then I'm not sure why your expecting `3` and `5`? It sounds like the two tables contain 15 records all linked to 1 unique `id`. Can you elaborate on where the `3` and `5` come from?...

Comment: table consulta - have 3 rows and table asesoria have 5 rows which are containing userID = 64 for example.   so from the main table users I am selectinc userID 64 and then selectinc all the rows in consulta and asesoria where userID= 64

Comment: by the way I have changed the ID names of the columns for consulta and asesoria and the result is still wrong.

Comment: John, SQL Count function counts also Nulls. Your query gives you the right result (you use the wrong query for your purpose). You have two possibilities. Either write a proper query and filter the null value, or use a SUM function after converting a non-null values to 1 and null values to 0.

Answer (score 0):

With the statement "any help will be welcome" I throw this out there to see if it does what you mean.

```
$sql="select *,
    ( select count( distinct s.`userID` ) from `consulta` ) as 'count_consulta',
    ( select count( distinct a.`userID` ) from `asesoria` ) as 'count_asesoria'
    from `users` c
        left outer join `consulta` s on s.`userID`=c.`userID`
        left outer join `asesoria` a on a.`userID`=c.`userID`
    group by c.`userID` desc;";
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select count distinct s.userID from consulta as count_consulta, select co' at line 2